# Crate motor for 2004 Dodge Neon

Tags: engine, dodge, neon

I'm looking for a good source to get a crate motor. I've tried some google searches but only found motors with high milage on them. I'm trying to decide on getting a crate or just rebuilidng existing motor. Currently has 110k but has an oil leak and it was abused in it's previous life.

Any sources on a long block crate? I'm hoping for under $1k shipped. It's a 2004 Dodge Neon RT non turbo.

I have a spare vehicle so the car can be down for a period of time. Would a speed shop do the work for me? What would be a good price for a rebuild having a shop do the removal/install too?

Comment: Why do you want to rebuild or replace the engine? The only thing you mention being wrong is an oil leak?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only people I can think of that would carry a crate motor are the dealers, or an authorized Mopar distributor. Not sure if it can be had anywhere else, and still be affordable.

Comment: Thanks. Dealers are usually 20% more expensive thats why I would rather go else where first, but I have had no luck and I think I have to go to a dealer. Too bad this isn't a chevy, those things grow on trees.

Comment: @Dustin Haha. Very true.